# Issue with setting up Oracle Rest Data services

Tags: oracle, rest, oracle-apex, oracle-ords

I have successfully installed Oracle REST Database Services version 3.0.4.60.12.48. I am able to access Oracle Apex but when I create a web-service and click on test button I get this error.

> Error during evaluation of resource template: GET hr/employees/,
>   SQL Error Code: 28000,
>   SQL Error Message: ORA-28000: the account is locked

I have tried connecting to `Oracle_apex_public` user and every other user to check if any account is locked but I am able to connect to these account with SQLDeveloper.

I have also tried reinstalling and changing default tablespace inside ORDS configuration files, but still it's not working.

If anyone has an idea what is going wrong, please help.

Comment: Is that the first error that you get on first execution? Accounts get automatically locked when you try too often to login with a wrong username/password. The lock is temporary. So if you happen to have called the `GET` method often and first you got lots of `invalid username/password` you may end up locking the account yourself and by the time you log on with SQLDeveloper it' unlocked again. Or the account may be just locked. You can find that out by querying [`DBA_USERS.ACCOUNT_STATUS`](http://docs.oracle.com/database/122/REFRN/DBA_USERS.htm#REFRN23302).

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the response.

I manage to solve the issue, the cause was i was using same Passwords for all apex public and sys changing th